# Angular (15) Unable to extend a typed FormGroup

Tags: angular, forms

I am messing around with typed FormGroup.

I created the following:

```
export interface CustomFormControls {
  name: FormControl<string|null>
  content: FormControl<string|null>
}

export class CustomForm extends FormGroup<CustomFormControls> {
    constructor() {
        super({
            name: new FormControl('name'),
            content: new FormControl('content'),
        })
    }
}
```

and then I am trying to use it in a component:

```
form: CustomForm = new CustomForm()
```

and in my template:

```
<form class="Form" [formGroup]="form">
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Type 'CustomForm' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup<any>'.
  Types of property 'controls' are incompatible.
    Type 'CustomFormControls' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }'.
      Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'CustomFormControls'.
         <form class="Form" [formGroup]="form">
```

I am not sure to understand what I did wrong in there.

Comment: I think you have to add index signature for string key in your interface export interface CustomFormControls {
  name: FormControl<string|null>
  content: FormControl<string|null>
  [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>;
}

Comment: Indeed, I tried it but my compiler misled me but you right indeed. I was hoping Angular would somehow do it for you, but it is what it is I guess. Thanks!

Comment: If you're adding controls with unknown keys, you can use a FormRecord: https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formrecord

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding an index signature for a string key

```
export interface CustomFormControls {
  name: FormControl<string|null>
  content: FormControl<string|null>
  [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface CustomFormControls {
  [key: string]: AbstractControl<string, string>;
  name: FormControl<string|null>;
  content: FormControl<string|null>;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.